# Ubuntu PyQT6 works from apt but not in a virtualenv through pip

Tags: pip, pyqt6, ubuntu-23.10

When trying to follow a tutorial for PyQT6 (on Ubuntu 23.10) I create a virtual environment, activate it and then I install PyQT6 through pip. When that is done and I try to run a basic program that is supposed get an empty window up and running. Instead however I get an error.

When installing PyQT6 through apt and not using a virtualenv everything works, the empty window appears as expected.

Here is what I tried:

Make the virtualenv and activate it:
`python -m venv venv`
`source venv/bin/activate`

Install PyQT6:
`python -m pip install pyqt6`

Try out this basic part from a book and save it as myapp.py:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Try to run it:
`python myapp.py`

And get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jon/Documents/Programming/python/create_gui_applications_with_python_pyqt6/myapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
ImportError: /home/jon/Documents/Programming/python/create_gui_applications_with_python_pyqt6/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZN14QReadWriteLock16destroyRecursiveEP21QReadWriteLockPrivate, version Qt_6_PRIVATE_API
```

Install PyQT6 through APT instead:
`sudo apt install python3-pyqt6`

And now the example code works when not using a virtualenv:
`python myapp.py`
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YCLp.png)

However I would still like to get things running inside a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Today, installing PyQt6 with `python -m pip install pyqt6` also installs PyQt6-Qt6 in v6.6.1 (released on Nov 30th). Using the previous version of PyQt6-Qt6 instead solved for me: `pip install --upgrade PyQt6-Qt6==6.6.0`

*Long explaination*

Like you, today after a fresh installation of my python package, I am no more able to run it, while it worked a week ago. It produces the same error as you:

```
ImportError: [...]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PyQt6/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZN14QReadWriteLock16destroyRecursiveEP21QReadWriteLockPrivate, version Qt_6_PRIVATE_API
```

What changed ?!

It can only come from my package dependencies. Indeed I am still on the same OS version and same Python version.

My package only frozen `PyQt6==6.6.0` but not its dependencies.

Looking at `PyQt6==6.6.0` dependencies, it depends on `PyQt6-Qt6` that released  the version 6.6.1 on Nov 30th (https://pypi.org/project/PyQt6-Qt6/6.6.1).

This is a possible breaking change from my previous installation!

I tried using the previous version 6.6.0 of PyQt6-Qt6:

`pip install --upgrade PyQt6-Qt6==6.6.0`

And it works for me.

Adrien